# Predict outcome for Dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

Is there a function to predict outcome in dygraphs? I would like to predict the following month based on this data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLLRs.png

Anyone able to help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dygraphs seems like only a Javascript charting library (for time-series) and does not offer any statistical methods. https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/tree/master/src

I would recommend that you would do the prediction in the same place where you create that initial data for that chart and then create new chart with that additional data.

Although I'm not sure what algorithm to use to make predictions from that data. Probably the simplest way with that kind of linear data is to use [linear regression](http://linear%20regression%20in%20python), but I would recommend diving in depth to [statistics](https://www.udacity.com/courses/data-science) to make better predictions.